# Read, Edit, Data Handle of SQLite 2.1 database enclosed in "php" file

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a php file which as far as I can understand contain the database  of a website build using a kind of "Site Builder" under Plesk. Since I have to other way to edit his website anymore ("Site Builder" is a dead project and no way to convert it to something else...) I try to access and manipulate the data of this "php" database.

I open the file to "Notepad++" and I see only strange characters, nothing like the "php" files I open and edit in the past.
After a quick search I realize that this is a "SQLite 2.1 database" but the "php" extension is not what is expected.
Is there a way to access and edit the data of this php database?

Comment: This description makes little sense for me. Post that file (in full or part) instead.

Comment: The php file is more than 100k lines with strange characters. I can't post it here. In any case what maybe can help is that it starts with "This file contains an SQLite 2.1 database "

Comment: OK, so if the chars looks odd, please open it in your editor and update question with the screenshot?

Comment: Sqlite 2.1 was the current version in fall **2001**. This could be a fun bit of software archaeology.

Comment: As a start you can check out sqlite releases that old from the official source repository and try to get them building.

Comment: Still no idea how to handle sqlite db in php file..
Where I have to start?

Comment: `sqlite in php file` is what makes little sense for me here. I'm guessing its just sqlite's db file but named with `.php` suffix? If so, forget the file name and use sqlite module to accessing the db

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try.
Do I have to rename the file to "sqlite" and then use something like this `$db = new SQLite3("database.sqlite") or die('Not able to open file.');`
or I can handle the file without renaming using something like this `$db = new SQLite3("database.php") or die('Not able to open file.');`

Comment: Unfortunately i get error "file is not a database". I try both the original "php" file and I also try a renamed to "sqlite" version without success